# QtConcurrent::run() doesn't accept __stdcall/WINAPI function

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, stdcall, qtconcurrent

I was trying to execute a DLL function that has `__stdcall` calling convention using `QtConcurrent::run()`, but I am getting compile errors.

I've reduced the problem to this example code:

```
__stdcall void dllFunc() {
    qDebug() << "test";
}

void test() {
    QtConcurrent::run(dllFunc);
}
```

If I remove `__stdcall` the code compiles and runs fine. Otherwise I get these compile errors:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)()' to 'void (*)()'
error:   initializing argument 1 of 'QFuture<T> QtConcurrent::run(T (*)()) [with T = void]'
```

Why is this happening, and what is the best workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for a workaround, I ended up using a wrapper function with the same signature but no `__stdcall` convention:

```
__stdcall int dllFunc(int param1, void *param2) {
    qDebug() << "test";
    return 0;
}

int dllFuncWrapper(int param1, void *param2) {
    return dllFunc(param1, param2);
}

void test() {
    QtConcurrent::run(dllFuncWrapper);
}
```